# boost exception's error info

Tags: c++, exception, boost

When using [`boost::exception`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/exception/doc/boost-exception.html), what is the preferred way to know what data the exception is carrying? In the [boost documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/exception/doc/motivation.html) the following example is given:

```
catch( io_error & e )
    {
    std::cerr << "I/O Error!\n";

    if( std::string const * fn=get_error_info<file_name>(e) )
        std::cerr << "File name: " << *fn << "\n";

    if( int const * c=get_error_info<errno_code>(e) )
        std::cerr << "OS says: " << strerror(*c) << "\n";
    }
```

This seems to be a bit awkward, especially if the exception bubbled through a lot of layers and has a load of metadata theoretically available. So I guess it makes sense to document what the possible error infos are for each exception class. Then I probably also need documentation for some functions, about what information might be in the exceptions. In the end I feel like I have the exact same structure in documentation, as I would have in code if I just used something like the following struct:

```
struct FileException {
  string* filename; // NULL or string
}
```

I could then change this information in a catch block:

```
catch (FileException& e) {
  e.filename = filename;
  throw;
}
```

This simple way I would get around most of the documentation, and profit from all of the safety (e.g. not trying to get filenames from `MathException`). Yet people use boost. Is there a big advantage of the dynamic approach that I'm missing? How do you document the error infos in your code?

Answer (score 1):

From a very high level, you can refer to the diagnostic information of that exception:
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/exception/doc/diagnostic_information.html

This will print everything the exception carries (and a little more). I'm not sure if there is a way to get at all of the internal stuff individually...

From the examples:

```
example_io.cpp(70): Throw in function class boost::shared_ptr<struct _iobuf> __cdecl my_fopen(const char *,const char *)
Dynamic exception type: class boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<struct fopen_error>
std::exception::what: example_io error
[struct boost::errinfo_api_function_ *] = fopen
[struct boost::errinfo_errno_ *] = 2, "No such file or directory"
[struct boost::errinfo_file_name_ *] = tmp1.txt
[struct boost::errinfo_file_open_mode_ *] = rb
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can change or design your exception to include what you require to describe the error, do it as you want. but if exception is not generated by your code or you don't have access to the error information when you generate the error then you need the dynamic approach of `error_info`. For example think we have a `read` free function that read data from a C++ file object that does not contain a file name in it as follow:

```
void read( file& fp, std::vector<unsigned char>& buf ) {
    if( fread(&buf[0], 1, buf.size(), fp.getFile()) == -1 ) {
        // I don't know the file name, what should I do here??
        boost::throw_exception( io_error() );
    }
}

try {
    file fp( "/path/to/file" );
    // do some thing with fp
    read( fp, buffer );
} catch( io_error& e ) {
    e << file_name( "/path/to/file" ); // here I can provide file name
    throw;
}
```

as you see `error_info` designed for case that I have to add data to the error incrementally, but if on throw site I have all required information then I can embed those information in exception class and avoid using `error_info`

Comment: i understand that application, but why can't you just fill the sample `struct` from my question in the `catch` block and rethrow it?

Comment: sometime you are working on an application and you are using all libraries to complete your task, now you are absolutely free to use any kind of tool to complete your task, for example you can throw a non `std::exception` and every thing will work fine. but sometime you are working on a library that just come between 2 other portion of code, then you can't change any thing and also it have a little performance benefit to use `error_info` over create a new structure and rethrow it

Comment: but only assuming that the other two libraries also use boost exceptions, right? is there a benefit from using this for a new project over using my own exception classes? how would i document the usage of error info?

Comment: no, dynamic `error_info` is excellent because a library can use `std::exception` and you use `boost::error_info` in your program! it's wonderful, isn't it??

Comment: sorry, i don't get it. i can't attach `error_info` to non-boost exceptions, can i? so if the library throws a `std::exception` based thing, i have to rethrow it as `boost::exception` anyway?

Comment: You are correct, you can't attach `error_info` for non-boost exceptions but any library can handle them as normal `std::exception` and also you can add error info to any non-boost exception by using a general library function `boost::enable_error_info` and beside that you can add common error info to any exception. consider you have 3 kind of exception and you want to add information of current logged in user to them. one way is defining new class and throw it but another is add a global function that add it as `error_info`. most important feature of `error_info` is its unique architecture!!

Comment: Okay, I think I'm starting to get it. But to the second part of my question, how do you document the usage of `error_info` properly?

Comment: You should only include short common information in `error_info`, not all information. information that is natural to the error must moved to the exception class and more common or layered information will be added as `error_info`. this way you should not have many `error_info` and their explanation and documentation depend on you.

Comment: I'd like to speak a bit to what @BigBoss is saying. You do not need to document error_info at all. Each layer passes the exception up, optionally adding information to it. Finally, any layer that decides to print simply calls `diagnostic_information()` to dump the exception. The assumption of Boost is that granular access to information is not needed as much as dynamic information insertion (yes, reiterating).

Answer (score 0):

The advantage of the "dynamic approach" is that a file name isn't only relevant to FileException objects. For example, if you open a script file that contains a math expression which when parsed throws a MathException, you still want that exception to carry the file name. In general, the call stack between the throw site and the catch site can not know about all possible types of exception objects that may pass through it, yet it often has relevant information that should be stored in them.